# generate array list of dynamic type in java

Tags: java

what I have is a super class

```
class Geometry{
}
```

and two classes that extends it:

```
class ShapeOne extends Geometry{}

class ShapeTwo extends Geometry{}
```

what I want to achieve is to generate a list(read from the database) of objects of the type `ShapeOne` or `ShapeTwo` or any other that is instance of `Geometry`, but dynamically passing the type as a parameter,
for example like:

```
public ArrayList< Geometry Object > getList(/**passing typeof generated list**/){
  // getting data from Database;
  return new ArrayList<typeof generated list>();
}

so the call would be then like:
 getList(ShapeTwo);
```

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by passing `Class<T>`, like this:

```
public <T extends GeometryObject> List<T> getList(Class<T> itemClass) throws Exception {
    List<T> res = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
        res.add(itemClass.newInstance());
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/0Kmlyq)

Note: the above call to `newInstance` assumes that the class has a parameterless constructor.

Comment: ok, than my <T> class should have a static newInstance(), right?

Comment: @user1908375 `Class<T>` already provides [`newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) method. You do need a parameterless constructor in order for this to work.

Comment: ...only if the class has a public default (no-args) constructor.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that. Due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), `List<Geometry>` is not a super class of `List<ShapeOne>`. This is better explained here: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/1065197).

Some alternatives to solve your problem:

- Return `List<ShapeOne>` or `List<ShapeTwo>` or `List<TheExpectedClass>` rather than `List<Geometry>`.
- Return `<T extends Geometry> List<T>` and pass `Class<T> clazz` as argument. Probably you would need to use an additional parameter to recognize if the data recovered from database belongs to a specific subclass of `Geometry`.